# What is the purpose of asterix (*) in Gcode?

Tags: g-code

Doing some low level monitoring, the following sequence is sent to the printer:

```
N0 M106*36 
N1 G28*18 
N2 M107*39
```

This sequence just turns the fan on, homes the printer, then turns the fan off.

Question: What is the purpose of the asterix/star/(*) and the two succeeding digits on each line?

Comment: * asterisk - [Asterix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterix) is a character in a cartoon series.

Comment: @AndrewMorton So that would make the gcode the Romans then - with Asterix being their checksum, stopping corruption in his local area?

Comment: Hmmm... maybe. The Romans did build a lot of things, like a 3-d printer does.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is a checksum. It's added by the host software to the G-code, to allow some basic verification by the firmware that the G-code was transmitted unchanged. It doesn't change the meaning of the G-code, and what your sequence actually represents is just `M106, G28, M107`. The `N0,N1,N2,...` are line numbers, and the combination of line numbers and checksums is used to request a re-send of any lines that were corrupted during transmission.

Comment: Do you happen to know the checksum algorithm used here?

Comment: In Marlin, all the bytes for the individual characters are XOR-ed together, and the result should be the same as the checksum.

Comment: Just XOR: `byte checksum = 0;
        byte count = 0;
        while(instruction[count] != '*')
                checksum = checksum^instruction[count++];`