# G-code commands gets multiplied by random number

Tags: g-code

The G-code sent from Octopi to my printer gets multiplied at the end of every row.
The corresponding code out of Simplify3D do not have that multiplication.

This results in a always Max speed print.

1 month ago all worked perfect.

Have anyone seen this problem before? How to solve?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE! According to [this answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/3118/11242), the asterisks at the end followed by a number is just a checksum, used to ensure what's going out is what's coming in ... this should have absolutely no affect on how your printer behaves.

Comment: Thank you @PAULSTER2. And I though i searched the web :). Then I'll have to find my problem with the printer not reduceding the speed at for example first layer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that everything after the "*" is a comment.  From the random variation, I speculate that the comments for Octoprint are a check code.  For other host programs, it is a sequence number.

@oscar linked to a previous answer in a comment which shows that it is a checksum.  I will need to check the next time I run Repetier Host, but that seemed to be a sequence number.  Please see Oscar's comment (and upvote it).

Comment: Please look into [What is the purpose of asterix (\*) in Gcode?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/3118/what-is-the-purpose-of-asterix-in-gcode) to read about the asterisk character in a G-code.